# Where are the form elements allowed within a table element?

Tags: html

I want to create a table with search textbox above the column headings as such

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Mother</td><td>Father</td></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="search-results">
      <!-- to be populated by AJAX response -->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Is the form element allowed like this?

```
<form>
  <thead>...</thead>
</form>
```

or

```
<thead>
  <form>...</form>
</thead>
```

or which way?

Also, can `<input type="hidden" />` be place absolutely anywhere between the form tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the entire `<table>` element in `<form>`, you cannot put anything which is not table related inside `<table>` except for inside `<th>`, `<td>` and `<caption>` elements. So if you do not want to put the entire form in a `<td>` cell, you should wrap the entire table in `<form>`.

`<input type="hidden">` tags are just like any other input tags - they must be wrapped inside `<td>` and other content tags.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a table, a `<form>` can only be where content goes inside the table which would be inside a `<td>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<th>` or `<caption>`.  Or the entire table can be inside the `<form>`, but not either of the ways you show it.

You can also use form elements like `<input>` tags or other form elements in any `<td>` without enclosing them in a `<form>` if you aren't using the built-in form submission capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is the specification on html5, you will find out that only form embedded into a table is allowed [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)

This is the correct form of using thead : [thead tutorial](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/tables/thead-tbody/).

The below content is copied from that link to preserve the answer if the link gets discarded:

> If you want, you can leave your tables like this, but if you
>   appreciate content that are highly semantically structured I am glad
>   to introduce you to the  element. The  element
>   structures the headings in your table and this tells browsers what
>   e.g. each column contains. The  element structures all of the
>   content, so that the browser knows what the actual content of the
>   table is. Using the same example as before, the  and the
>    elements are to b used like this:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                        <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
                        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 1</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 1</td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 1</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Also you can use hidden input anywhere in the form tag.